# How to check if substring of string's array match to patterns from other string array

Tags: groovy

I wonder if there is any groovy-way to check if substring of strings matches to patterns.

For example I have strings List (or array):

`def Errors = ['File xyz cannot be created: No space left on device', 'File kjh has errors: some_error']`

Then I have list of strings, for example `def Patterns = ['Tests failed', 'No space left on device', 'Something goes wrong', ...some strings... ]`

I would like to check if some elements of List `Patterns` are substrings of  `Errors` elements .

In that example it should return true, because `Patterns` has `No space left on device` and `Errors` has `'File xyz cannot be created: No space left on device'`.

I know how to write it very ulgy and not efficient by using two for loops and method `contains`, but I know that Groovy has much more powerfull built-in methods. I have tried with `findAll()`, but it doesnt worked at all.

Do you have any ideas? Is there any way to make it more clever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly naming `pattern` and `error`:

```
patterns.find { pattern -> errors.find { error -> error.contains(pattern) } }  // -> No space left on device
patterns.any { pattern -> errors.find { error -> error.contains(pattern) } } // -> true
```

depending on what/how many you want to find.

Or even shorter:

```
patterns.find { errors.find { error -> error.contains(it) } }
patterns.any { errors.find { error -> error.contains(it) } }
```